# Classificação de conjunção "que"

Tags: conjunções

No fragmento *"O Governo vai gastar mais dinheiro com cadeia. Falam que lá dentro não é facil, **que** aqui sim é uma escolinha."* o **"que"** destacado é uma conjunção subordinativa de qual tipo?

Certo professor me disse que seria o caso de conjunção subordinativa integrante, mas sua resposta não me convenceu. Poderiam me esclarecer?

Comment: O que destacado e o imediatamente anterior introduzem orações que representam objetos diretos. Assim, as orações em questão são orações subordinadas substantivas objetivas diretas. As conjunções que introduzem orações subordinadas substantivas são conjunções subordinativas integrantrs.

Comment: Obrigado, @AiltonAndradedeOliveira! Agora entendi!

Answer (score 2):

São, sim, conjunções subordinativas integrantes:

> O que destacado e o imediatamente anterior introduzem orações que representam objetos diretos.
>   Assim, as orações em questão são orações subordinadas substantivas objetivas diretas.
>
> As conjunções que introduzem orações subordinadas substantivas são conjunções subordinativas integrantes.